# Scalability of Scrum

Tags: scrum, agile, project-team, risk-management

Is scrum scalable? Can it be employed in large scale non-IT projects?

I have gone through some articles and views on the Internet, which suggest that scrum can be employed in non-IT projects. But I am not sure to what extent.

Comment: You need to better qualify what you mean by scalable. This question is easily answerable with very simple search query. You've tagged it with *risk management* and *project team* for what reasons?

Comment: What problem are you facing Victor? Are you trying to implement Scrum in your organization? What type of projects do you do? Tell us more details that will help you get the best answers possible. I put new answers on hold to give you some time to make additional edits. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

Is Scrum scalable? Initially, Agile authors believed that Agile methodologies including Scrum was predominantly for small scale projects. This opinion was based on the fact that Scrum had not yet been applied on large scale projects. The Guide to the Scrum Body of Knowledge (SBOK™ Guide) gives comprehensive directions through which Agile methodologies including Scrum, can be scaled and applied on larger projects.